# Effective 2D array's delta data structure

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I'm making a prototype and currently not sure how to design one loaded gear.

Its purpose is simple - saving 2D array's delta and return it later as getDelta(i,j) or via any other interface. The best compression isn't needed right now, just not an O^2 of array's size memory, but the performance is.

**Details:**

1. Forming delta to asking the whole array's delta in some order operation rate is 1:1.
2. Currently, there stored a float data, but I don't want to pin this as an implementation detail.
3. Delta got fixed size; it's the same as an array's rows amount (or columns; array is always square, in addition).
4. This is possible to refit consumer and writer code to put and read in the same (or any other mutually known) order, but I don't know, which is the best way to use this to optimize it.

*p.s. It's a Java task, but as a general data-structure issue: C, Perl, Mathematica, Fortran, pseudo-code or ideas are welcome, other language based examples may be not so clear for me.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To efficiently store "delta" (i.e., the difference) between two 2D arrays in case most of the values are expected to be the same, you can use a [hash map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or a [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) to store the values just for the elements which are different.

A quick implementation in C++:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef float value_type;
vector<vector<value_type>> original_array;
map<pair<int, int>, value_type> different_elements;

void calculate_delta(const vector<vector<value_type>> &another_array) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < original_array.size(); ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < original_array[i].size(); ++j) {
           if (another_array[i][j] != original_array[i][j]) {
               // store the different element
               different_elements.insert(make_pair(make_pair(i, j),
                                                   another_array[i][j]);
           }
        }
    }
}

value_type get_delta(int i, int j) {
    auto it = different_elements.find(make_pair(i, j));
    if (it == different_elements.end()) {
        return original_array[i][j];
    }
    return it->second; // return the stored value
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If we speak about efficiency - the map interface implementation matters here. Which kinds are your suggested maps (except attached hash map/table)? 
 
In the first version, I'd produce the similar code with HashMap(you linked it too) and SortedMap(implementation of the black-red trees). It showed as a too slow approach - new key object generations and hashes operations ^2 from matrix size, also this is a memory and related operations overhead (not stored outside, but garbage collected or destructed in the C case).

Comment: @Les Generating a key for insertion and lookup in a hash map has `O(1)` time complexity. The *expected* complexity of lookup and insertion itself, assuming an okay-ish hash function is `O(1)` as well. And the actual implementations of maps and hash maps in all main programming languages are pretty efficient as well. Quantify what is "too slow" for you and give the details (code) about the approaches you have already considered.

Comment: Yes, the theoretical O(1) is still awful performance here. Sorry for a remark, but I say the same phrase often to my colleagues from academic computer science. Better angle to the problem is that there is an O("array side size"^2) for the whole delta put or get bulk operation. I solve this for a tour based delta writing only two primitive arrays (deltas and their rows idx, another info contained in a primitive arrays' elements order), but the upper problem still interests me.